# Extract $keyword from a php search form

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, echo, keyword

Here is my search function :

```
class Ads extends Controller
{
    public function search($format='velos', $cat='occasion', $location='france', $keyword, $page=1)
    {
        if($format == 'velos')
        {
            $query = '`private`=0';
        } else
        {
            $query = '`private`=1';
        }
    $this->images($query, $cat, $location,'MATCH(title) AGAINST ("'.db::escape($keyword).'" IN BOOLEAN MODE)', $page, '%s/%s/%s/'.$keyword.'/%d/', $row[0], $keyword);
    }
}
```

It's working fine, when I change the keyword in the URL, everything is okay
But I would like to echo that keyword in the page, I don't know how ?
I tried

```
<?php echo $keyword; ?>
```

But the echo doesn't return anything. There might be a scope issue, but I'm not sure.

EDIT 
Actually the $keyword comes from a search field, but from another class, that's maybe why I was thinking of a scoping issue

```
class UserModel extends Model
{
    public function search_form()
    {
    $form = new Form('search_form');

    $form->field('keyword', 'text', array
    (           
        'optional'      =>  true
    )); 
    if($data = $form->validate())
    {
        header('Location: '.WEB.sprintf($data['parts_search'].'/'.$data['category_search'].'/'.$data['location_search'].'/'.$data['keyword'].'/1/'));
    }
    return $form;
    }   
}
```

Solution :

It might not be the best solution, but actually the only one I found :

```
$url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
$path = $parts['path'];
$keys = explode('/', $path);
echo $keys[4]; // `corresponding to the 4th url word`
```

Comment: I think echo'ed text was hidden under some markup. did u try checking in view source?

Comment: you can use die or exit functions to exit the execution and see the output

Comment: Can you be more concrete ? I'm a beginner in php.. Should I do a var_dump ?

Comment: echo $keyword = strrev($keyword);exit(); try this

Comment: @VenuGopalT it doesn't do anything, page is empty

Comment: silly mistake here, put echo in front of $keyword :P

Comment: the search function is actually contained in a class `class Ads extends Controller` and var_dump from the echo returns NULL, is it a scope issue ?

Comment: `$keyword = echo $keyword;` returns `syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO`

Comment: its better to first echo a text to make sure things are coming on your browser and $keyword is not empty, null etc.  do echo "keyword is $keyword"; exit();

Comment: yep, I tried but echo is empty, var_dump returns NULL... Anyway it's messy with all the classes and functions, you'd need the whole code to understand how it works :/ Thanks for helping, I just give up for the moment, it's way over my skills...

Comment: Simply your printing the $keyword variable. check whether your passing the $keyword parameter for that function. Because there is no other manipulation you performed by that variable.

Comment: look for the place from where your search function is getting called and try to print $keyword from there to just make sure there is some value in $keyword.

Comment: I updated the post to show you the search form function, which is in another class. But my webpage displays the other class (Ads) after using the search form, that's maybe why echo is NULL

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there is a way to extract a word from an URL ?

Comment: If your using any framework, tell that..! that may us to understand the exact problem. If yes, you should added that tag also in question.
Because, In some framework, you will pass the parameter value by URL like codeignitor, cakephp.

Comment: if you have in you url http://.....php?keyword=toto you can extract it by $keyword = $_GET['keyword']

Comment: @Sakthi I'm using codeigniter

Comment: @Jamescoo can u give your url while you searching something..?

Comment: I think Your passing the url like localhost/ur-root-folder/controller-name/function-name/your-keyword-to-search. If so, It is wrong. Because you need to pass the "your-keyword-to-search" parameter in 4th parameter.

Comment: I updated the post cause I found a solution (not the best actually)
@Sakthi my search URL is http://www.veloccasion.net/velos/occasion/france/mykeyword/1/

Comment: remove all your routing(related to this controller)from your project. and try controller/function/parameter1/p2/p3/p4/ and then put die('test='.$keyword) after the function start and see. If you didn't get the "test--ur keyword--" keyword, something is wrong in somewhere. Not pblm is in your function. And check your route.php in config folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding exaclty what the problem is, but based on your proposed solution, there is an auto-loaded CI class that can do what you've proposed.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

So, for
http://yoursite.com/format/cat/location/yourKeyword

```
$keyword = $this->uri->segment(4); // get the 4th segment of my CI URI
echo $keyword; // prints yourKeyword
```

Hope this helps.